# Problems configuring Serilog from appSettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, serilog

I have a question relating the configuration of Serilog by appSettings.json.
My project is a console application, based on .Net Core 3.0.
I tried to setup Serilog in order to write log information to the console and to a log file.

When I configure everything within my code itself - everything works like expected.

But when I try to import the Serilog configuration settings from an appsettings.json file, I have the problem, that my ConsoleSink works fine, but my FileSink not.

Here is, what I wrote into my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": { "pathFormat": "Xlog.txt" }
      },
      { "Name": "Console" }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is the associated code:

```
  IConfiguration configSerilog = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .Build();


            log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(configSerilog)
                 .CreateLogger();


            log.Information("Initializing Serilog....");
```

My 'test-log-message' get's displayed in my console window, but I didn't get a logfile.

As I mentioned, it works, when I configure the Serilog in my code itself, rather than by the appsettings.
So, I do have the appropriate access rights to create a file.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: search `Serilog SelfLog` and/or use Sysinternals Filemon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that file proprieties for `appsettings.json`, property "**Copy to Output Directory**" is "**Copy always**" or "**Copy if Newer**".

And update youe configration as below (`pathFormat` in `Args` shoud be `path`)

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": { "path": "Xlog.txt" }
      },
      { "Name": "Console" }
    ]
  }
}
```